# HTTP library that doesn't depend on HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, unity-game-engine

I need a C# HTTP library that doesn't depend on HttpWebRequest, as I can't access this from the environment I need to run my code (Unity's WebPlayer).

Ideally this would be light weight, but any suggestions are welcome!

I just need to be able to do simple HTTP GET and POST requests, but better REST support would be good.

Thanks!

**Edit**: As people have pointed out, HttpWebRequest isn't in System.Web, but the fact remains - I can't use it. I've updated my post above.

This post
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/24445-NotSupportedException-System.Net.WebRequest.GetCreator shows the same error I'm getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing your own simple HTTP client using Socket is not all that difficult.

Just use TcpClient().

For the protocol itself, drop down to a connection-per-request paradigm. A typical GET request would look as follows:

```
GET /url HTTP/1.1
Host: <hostname-of-server>
Connection: close
```

For the code itself (from memory)

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
IPEndPoint target = ... // get an endpoint for the target using DNS class
client.Connect(target);

using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
// send the request.
string request = "GET /url HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request));

// then drain the stream to get the server response
}
```

Note that you will need to wrap this code with a simple class that provides HTTPWebRequest like semantics.

Comment: Yep, this is what I've done, essentially. It seems odd nobody has written a library like this. It's easy for the basic cases, but gets more complex with multi-part MIME etc.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`.

It is in `System.dll`.

**Documentation:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

`HttpRequest` is located in `System.Web`, which is probably what you were thinking of.

Comment: You're right - but I still can't use HttpWebRequest. I've edited the question.

Comment: @eAi, did you read the answer in that post? "The only way to work around this is to somehow use the UnityEngine.WWW class instead of System.Net.WebClient"

Comment: Two posts down, dreamora says: "On webplayer its not supported for crossdomain security reasons at all in Unity 3, not a bug. If you want to do requests, you must use WWW **or implement it yourself on TCP Client / TCP Socket**". This second option is what I'm looking for - if it comes to it, I'll just implement it myself, but I'm sure others have done this before.

Comment: @eAi, I've never done this before, but good luck.   However, this sounds significantly different than the original question.  I think you'll be more likely to find an answer if you open another question specifically addressing "implementing a TCP Client/TCP Socket" for HTTP requests with Unity

Comment: It's still plain C# code - Unity purely limits what standard libraries we can use. I've mostly implemented my own HTTP code now, so maybe that's it. I'll open a new question if necessary!

Answer (score 1):

`HttpWebRequest` is in the `System` assembly, not in `System.Web` (perhaps you're confusing with `HttpRequest` which is used in ASP.NET). It is available in all .NET Framework versions (including Silverlight, WP7, and Client Profile)

Comment: You're right - but I still can't use HttpWebRequest. I've edited the question.